# Force Web AppBuilder to use HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, ssl

I have an out-of-the-box instance of ArcGIS Web AppBuilder developer edition - the startup.bat file is unmodified and includes the lines:

```
REM open the url in browser
START http://%FQDN%:%port%/%wabVirtualPath%
EXIT 0
```

However, when I start a new session on my PC, it runs as https://localhost:3344/webappbuilder - even if I forcibly change the URL to http:// it immediately reverts to https://

This is causing a problem when I try to access ArcGIS Server REST endpoints which are not served via https.

For example, when trying to add a sample layer via the [Local Layer Widget](https://github.com/cmndrbensisko/LocalLayer) I get an error message about insecure content:

[image]

I'm working in a corporate environment and don't have the option of serving my local layers via HTTPS, so I'd like to know whether it's possible to force Web AppBuilder to run on HTTP.

Comment: You won't be able to switch from https://...:3344 to http://...:3344 because the port will be associated with the protocol.

Comment: @nmtoken can I change that in the startup.bat file?

Comment: I expect you would need to change the port bindings on your web server, rather than on the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the signininfo.json file under this path "arcgis-web-appbuilder-X.X\WebAppBuilderForArcGIS\server"

Change the portalUrl either to http or https, this will make the WAB to use either http or https

[image]

Comment: it's been a while since I looked at this problem (I've since moved on to using GeoServer instead :) but from memory, this change didn't have any effect. I'll check it again if I start using WAB again